# Remove Lotus Notes design element inheritance programmatically

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

As part of an effort to create a rudimentary revision control system, I would like to programmatically disable design element level inheritance on a Lotus Notes template. I have so far tried the following:

- **DXL export (ForceNoteFormat=true) + XSLT.** This failed with a validation problem in the importer, on fields(!).
- **DXL export (ForceNoteFormat=false) + XSLT.** Seems to work, but I'd rather not use a DXL solution for something this general.

An area I would like to explore:

- **Loop over all (design) Notes, remove the `$Class` item.**

Does anybody have a suggestion on how to do this, or another approach that will remove inheritance?

Comment: ironically, I'd like to "programatically disable" Lotus Notes!

Comment: @Mitch: That I know how to do with DXL... :-)

Comment: It's problems like this, and [this other one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2248663/241142), that make me want to throw away Notes completely and exclusively use Ruby (and its gems), a much saner and better designed system for sharing code. Notes' system for sharing code is copy and paste.  It's too bad: Notes has many flashes of brilliance, but in the end it is death by 10,000 paper cuts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following sub seems to work, it removes the flag from any design element a 7.0.3 client can produce.  I got the clues about `NotesNoteCollection` from [Ian's blog](http://blog.ianchivers.com/wordpress/?p=25) entry on the same subject:

```
Private Sub clearDesignInheritance(db As notesdatabase)
    On Error Goto errorthrower

    Dim nc As NotesNoteCollection
    Set nc = db.CreateNoteCollection(True) ' Select all note types...
    nc.SelectDocuments=False ' ...except data documents.

    Call nc.BuildCollection

    Dim noteid As String
    noteid = nc.GetFirstNoteId

    Dim doc As notesdocument

    Do Until noteid=""
        Set doc = db.GetDocumentByID(noteid)
        If doc.HasItem("$Class") Then
            Call doc.RemoveItem("$Class")
            Call doc.save(False,False,False)
        End If
        noteid = nc.GetNextNoteId(noteid)
    Loop

    Exit Sub
ErrorThrower:
    Error Err, Error & Chr(13) + "Module: " & Cstr( Getthreadinfo(1) ) & ", Line: " & Cstr( Erl )
End Sub
```